# how to update a field on firebase web exactly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**when create a field on firebase and then firebase create a new field with auto id ,when update firebase create a new field differnce with id using uid, i would like create and update on the same field**

```
        async setCollectionUsers(data, user) {
        const posts = await firebase.firestore().collection("users")
            .add({
                firstName: user.firstName,
                lastName: user.lastName,
                uid: data.user.uid,
                createdAt: new Date(),
                isOnline: true
            });
        return posts;
    }
    async setCollectionUsersIsonline(data) {
        const posts = await firebase.firestore().collection("users")
            .doc(data.user.uid)
            .update({
                isOnline: true
            })
        return posts;
    }
```

I just want `update i field isonline but it add a new field`, im using set function then still like that .please help!

Answer (score 0):

This line will look up the doc which names 'data.user.id'.

`.doc(data.user.uid)`

If you want to find the result by uid you should use it like

```
const posts = await firebase.firestore()
    .collection("users")
    .where('uid', '==', uid)
    .get();
```

Rememeber this will return a post collection but a post itself.

Update

```
var usersRef = ref.child("users");
usersRef.set({
  alanisawesome: {
    date_of_birth: "June 23, 1912",
    full_name: "Alan Turing"
  },
  gracehop: {
    date_of_birth: "December 9, 1906",
    full_name: "Grace Hopper"
  }
});

var hopperRef = usersRef.child("gracehop");
hopperRef.update({
  "nickname": "Amazing Grace"
});
```

[See the full docs here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data)

Comment: firebase auto create a field id. so when update  not found uid ,uid a child colum id of firebase ,i want to update but not get value,i show image but stack overflow not allowed.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#section-update

Actually you can update the record in the callback in your first step.